# How to send a data URI collected via javascript to a Django Model field?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, data-uri

I want to use the signature_pad from https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad to attach an image to a Django Form that gets saved to a server. With the code I have, I can successfully download the image from the signature pad as well as upload an image to the server with a link to the image on the database via Django’s ImageField. However, I can’t get the signature image sent to the server.  I think the two remaining things I need to be able to do are:

1. Send the image to the `signature` field form.
2. Encode the image so I can save it to a server.

I’ve got a couple other non-essential questions: is the image data currently saved in signaturePad.toDataURL until it’s submitted? I don’t know enough to have a preference as to whether the image is sent to the server as a Data URI string or a link to a .PNG file. I imagine a string is easier to deal with down the road, correct?

Here's my models.py

```
from django.db import models

class testModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='signatures/')
    signature = models.FileField()
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import testModel

class testForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = testModel
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {'signature': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

from .Forms import testForm
from .Models import testModel

def testFormPage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = testForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        form = testForm()
    return render(request, 'testFormPage.html', {'form': form})
```

and the the HTML form:

```
<form action="{% url 'testFormPage' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad">
    <div class="signature-pad--body">
      <canvas></canvas>
      <button type="button" class="button save" data-action="save-png">Save as PNG</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="formSig.value" id="formSig">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Rather than copying the entire js app (https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad/tree/master/docs/js), here are the lines I added. I don't really know javascript so I've just tried to Frankenstein together what I've copied here and there.

```
var savePNGButton = wrapper.querySelector("[data-action=save-png]");
var formSig = wrapper.querySelector("[data-action=formSig]");

// and...
savePNGButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
    alert("Please provide a signature first.");
  } else {
    var dataURL = signaturePad.toDataURL();
    download(dataURL, "signature.png");
  }
});
formSig.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
    alert("Please provide a signature first.");
  } else {
    signature.value = signaturePad.toDataURL();
  };
```

Comment: Do you have the `signature` being submitted successfully in the data_uri format? Is it in cleaned_data?

Comment: You need to add the submit event listener to the form element

Comment: The form is not cleaned outside of the `is_valid()`  method in views.py. When I try to submit `signature` I receive the validation error: "(Hidden field signature) No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form." However, I have been successful uploading an image to an ImageField, as well as downloading the file as a PNG file as is done in the demo for signature_pad. I updated my post to show how I did those.

Comment: If you're submitting a file you need to set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the form tag

Comment: I did some digging and realized that too. I'm still getting the same validation error.

The more I've been working with this I think I have some clarity in what I need to know, so I edited my post to be more accurate. Thanks for your help so far!